# Java version update while executing cucumber scripts / code

Tags: cucumber

I have two queries :

1) Can i update the java version after i have installed all external libraries in IntelliJIDE while working on cucumber?

2) what is solution for  below error while i execute a basic code :

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/C:/Users/rahulp/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps/1.0.5/cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Comment: What is the java and cucumber versions? Seems u are using Java 9 and pretty ancient cucumber version. Use Java 8 and use latest cucumber version 4.2.6 - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java

Comment: I have java version as 11.0.2 and cucumber version is 4.2.6 , i installed the cucumber version just now from your link.